# PHP batch print

Tags: php, printing

Ι'm working on a project where a user creates a number of contracts (stored in a MySQL database) and then needs to print them all at once on his printer. I can't think of a way to perform this using PHP. I would like to simulate the browser printing process programatically for the number of contracts (ie, print contracts 1-50) in other words, how to print a large number of contracts at once without having to open each one on the browser and printing it from there.

Let me know if you need any further explanation. Thanks.

Comment: To clarify, do you want to print on the same machine PHP is running on, or the browser of the user? Printing: Local or Remote?

Comment: I need the user to print from the browser to his printer, not the same machine the PHP is running on.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is server-side, it has nothing to do with client-side printing. Rather use javascript's [`window.print`](http://www.google.com.ng/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/newtech2.shtml&ei=OQqDTpa2J9TE8QPu7-wJ&usg=AFQjCNGNyaEbU87gw0R_0SPRIWBPY89UYg) . However you cannot set print properties, that's left for the user to decide.

Comment: Please read my question again, I'm asking how to simulate the browser printing process programatically, in other words, how to print a large number of contracts at once without having to open each one on the browser and printing it from there.